# Figure positioning creates blank space at original position

Tags: floats, positioning, templates, white-space

I'm having problems with the autopositioning of my figures. While the positioning itself is fine, it seems the figures whitespace is created at the position in the latex code instead of around the figures final position.

I'm really not sure what causes this abnormal behavior.

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.     
\begin{center}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
             \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{figures/Anomaly_lit_filter.pdf}
        \caption{Algorithm Matrix for the reviewed DRL Libraries}
        \label{fig:DRL-library-algorithms}    
    \end{figure}
\end{center}
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

I'm using this latex template:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/phd-dissertation-and-doktorarbeit-latex-template-for-fau-friedrich-alexander-universitat-erlangen-nurnberg/tpmfykhzbkpz

Comment: First aid is always putting % signs at the end of each line. This looks like you are creating an accidental par skip here.

Comment: Remove the center environment and put a `\centering` command *inside* the figure!

Comment: Try removing the \begin{center} \end{center}. It creates - contrary to centering - additional space.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz it's not a paragraph, it's the `center` environment which is outside the floating - the figure will float and the center will stay...

Comment: You are right. I saw it a moment too late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`figure` (as `table`) environment creates a floating box. If you embed it in a `center` environment, when the box will float, a (blank) `center` environment is left back, with its  vertical space.

Use floating environments at the top level, with or without blank lines depending on if I want a paragraph end there:

```latex
    text text text 
    text text text 
    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
             \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{figures/Anomaly_lit_filter.pdf}
        \caption{Algorithm Matrix for the reviewed DRL Libraries}
        \label{fig:DRL-library-algorithms}    
    \end{figure}
    more text more text more text
```

The `\centering` (which is better than `\begin{center}...\end{center}` in this case, to avoid spurious spaces) will take care of the centering *inside* the floating box.

Comment: This solves the issue. I really did not link the center environment to this behavior. Thank you!